# Can we track Case Milestone's Start Date,Completion Date and Target Date?

Tags: apex, case, casemilestone

We would like to track the history of values in Start Date, Completion Date and Target Date fields on Case Milestones. I couldn't find any documentation about this on Salesforce Documentation site. Is there a Standard functionality to do this? or should use APEX to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce doesn't provide options to track histories for CaseMilestone object.

You need to create a custom object and store the values of each individual fields which you want to track.

Refer [Field History Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history.htm&type=0)

> You can track the field history of custom objects and the following standard objects.

- Accounts
- Articles
- Assets
- Campaigns
- Cases
- Contacts
- Contracts
- Contract line items
- Entitlements
- Leads
- Opportunities
- Orders
- Order Products
- Products
- Service Contracts
- Solutions